# Divergence of Tensor Field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

The author of this textbook is introducing this coordinate free definition of the divergence of tensor fields. Can someone help break this down for me, I am just really confused. First of all, does "a" represent a vector field? And then the the dot product of the two vector fields given by <div(T), a> would give us a scalar field right? Also, the right hand side of this equation would represent a scalar field as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[The Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RXwB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\r#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\p{\partial_i}
\def\c{\cdot}
\def\n{\nabla}
\def\a{a_k}
\def\T{T_{ik}}
$You will have a hard time proving the linked formula because it is **wrong.**

To see this, expand $\n\c\LR{T\c a}$ using the [Einstein summation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html) convention
$$\eqalign{
\p\LR{\T\a} &= \LR{\p\T}\a + \T\LR{\p\a} \\ 
}$$
then rearrange the terms
$$\eqalign{
\LR{\p\T}\a &= \p\LR{\T\a} - \T\LR{\p\a} \\ 
}$$
and convert back to vector notation
$$\eqalign{
\LR{\n\c T}\c a &= \n\c\LR{\r T\c a} - T:\LR{\n a} \\ 
}$$
or in terms of named operators
$$\eqalign{
{\op{div}\LR{T}}\c a &= \op{div}\LR{\r T\c a} - \op{trace}\LR{T^T\!\c{\n a}} \\ 
}$$
Note that the term in red is $\r{T^T}$ in the linked formula, which is incorrect.

$\sf NB\!:\:$ I could have expanded $\n\c\LR{T^T\c a}\,$
but then the linked document would have **two** typos instead of one, so the above is actually the most generous interpretation.